# How to open links in a python console application

Tags: python, windows, url, cmd

I'm trying to get myself a decent RSS reader in python. It's supposed to be a pure console application.
My question is-as mentioned in the title-how to open a link within this console. So e.g theres a recent feed entry and i want to click on it and it should open the linked website in a browser.
Is this possible and if yes I would be glad if you could help me

Comment: pretty sure it's impossible

Comment: You can however use a text command, like every other console application. It sounds like you want your console to be a GUI

Comment: What operating system are you using? My console has the feature you desire. In my console, all links are underlined and clickable. FYI, my console is gnome-terminal running in Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: unfortunately my os is windows 7

Comment: I don't know what "pure console application" means. Are you allowed to use [these functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682073(v=vs.85).aspx) ?

Comment: I certainly could do but idk if this would help. By console application I mean that theres no "seperate gui", just the standard output provided by windows 7

Comment: `import webbrowser` + http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682079%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using Windows, you can use Windows console functions to detect clicks on the console, translate the click positions (which will already be character positions) to links via hit-testing, and hook them up to e.g. `webbrowser.open` to open a link.

Input handling for console applications is described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682079%28v=vs.85%29.aspx.